# Make VPN server assign the connected computers to specific IP addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, dhcp, windows-server-2016

I have two virtual machines with Windows Server 2016 each on Hyper-V. First has active directory + DHCP role, second is VPN server (RAS role). In the DHCP, I have one address pool 192.168.1.32-192.168.1.55. When VPN clients connect to the VPN server, the DHCP assigns available IP addresses from that pool.

I want the DHCP to assign only specific IP addresses to the VPN clients. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static ip address pool in the properties of the RRAS server.

[image]

Comment: thanks, if I understand right, RRAS uses these addresses from the static pool, but these addresses may conflict with the DHCP on the ADDS virtual machine. Can I configure RRAS to choose IP addresses from a created pool on the DHCP so that there are no conflicts and the assignment stays permanent?

Comment: Create a RRAS pool that doesn't conflict with your existing DHCP pool.